# Quotient space and affine space

Tags: vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Sorry for many questions in this part. But I am still confused about the following:

From textbook "**Optimization by vector space**"(**Luenberger**):

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Problem:

I read the def. of quotient space many times; however, I find the def. of quotient space
is very like to the description above (**$x +$ subspace**). It seems affine subspace is one of quotient space. Is it true?

What on earth is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each element of a quotient of a vector space by a subspace is precisely a translation of that subspace, that is, a linear variety.