# Is $\textit{affine space}$ the same as $\textit{quotient space}$?

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-varieties

From the answer for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929945/quotient-space-and-affine-space), I understand that *affine subspace* is the same as *affine subset*, however (despite the somewhat misleading question's title), it doesn't say that *affine space* is the same as *quotient space*.

Also, I found the following definition of *affine space* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space):

> An affine space is a set A together with a vector space $\overrightarrow{A}$ and a transitive and free action of the additive group of $\overrightarrow{A}$ on the set $A$.

Which uses some terminologies, probably in Group theory, that I'm not familiar with. Some other "intuitive" explanations suggest to me that *affine space* is actually the same as *quotient space*.

Is that true that *affine space* is a synonym of *quotient space*?

Comment: You have the wp definition $(A, \vec A,+)$, where $A$ is a set, $\vec A$ is a vector space and $+ $ an action . $M+u$ is called the translated from point $M\in A $by the translation of vector $u\in \vec A$. What do you mean by "quotient space"?

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, @Paul Frost has provided the definition in his answer, which unarguably is a good one. (I chose your answer since it directly points to the thing that can help interpret the definition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocabulary "transitive and free action" refers to [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on a set.

You know vectors and points and relation between three points $A,B, C$:$$\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$$
Describing an affine space as in wikipedia definition you refer in OP is an equivalent way of describing a point space where two points $A$ and $B$ define a vector $\vec{AB}$.

Let $M$ a point and $u$ a vector. $$M+u \text{ refers to the point }M' \text{ s.t. }u=\vec{MM'}$$ In accordance with my comment, i.e. the translation of $M$ by the translation $t_u$ of vector $u$.

This equivalent definition in terms of the action of the additive group of vectors and this notation "$M+u$" is very convenient to define an affine **sub**space of $(A,\vec A,+)$ as $$M+V$$where $M\in A$ and $V$ is a linear **sub**space of $\vec A$.

$$\text{V is called the direction of M+V}$$

---

Now, if you consider the equivalence relation $\mathcal R$ on $A$ defined by$$M\mathcal R N\iff N\in M+V$$the equivalence classes are precisely the affine **sub**space of direction $V$.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The concepts of "affine space" and "quotient space" are by no means identical. In the linked question it was observed that the elements of a quotient space $V/V_0$, where $V$ is a vector space and $V_0 \subset V$ is a linear subspace, are the subsets of $V$ having the form $x + V_0$ with $x \in V$. Thus
$$V/V_0 = \{ x + V_0 \mid x \in V \} .$$

Clearly $x + V_0 = y + V_0$ iff $x - y \in V_0$.

For $x \notin V_0$ the set $x + V_0$ is not a linear subspace of $V$; it is a translated copy of $V_0$. The sets  $x + V_0$ are called *affine subspaces
of $V$*.

To understand the concept of an affine subspace you do not need to know the general concept of an affine space.

However, each affine subspace $x + V_0$ (which is no vector space unless $x \in V_0$, which means $x + V_0 = V_0$) can be regarded as affine space in the sense of the Wikipedia-definition. We simply define an action of $V_0$ on $x + V_0$ by
$$(u, x + v) \mapsto x + v + u .$$

You can easily verify the properties required in Wikipedia.